# how to make specific polynomials in a set with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sage

I am working with sagemath which uses the python language. In the polynomial ring over the integer ring, I want to  define a set whose elements have degree are less than a given number and the absolute value of coefficients are less than a given number.

How to achieve this? For a polynomial, I have defined  the degree function

and the max_coefficient function already.

For example,

```
(x^3-3*x-5).degree(x)      will return 3
max_coefficient(x^3-3*x-5) will return 5
```

The following are my codes.

```
R=Polynomialring(ZZ,x)

def A(deg_bound,coefficient_bound):
    S=set()
    for poly in R:
        if poly.degree(x)<=deg_bound and max_coefficient(poly)<=coefficient_bound:
            S=S.add(poly)
    return S
```

But sagemath tells me I can't do *for* in the polynomial ring.

Comment: `R = Polynomialring(ZZ, x)` what is this object exactly?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque This the polynomial ring over the integer ring. It is a ring, the underlying set consists elements a_0+a_1*x+...+a_n*x^n, with a_i are integers and x the indeterminate.

Comment: Is `R` iterable, and if yes, what are the items enumerated?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque  I am not familiar with the concept 'iterable', I am very new to programing. Since it is easy to deduce that the set I desire is finite, so I want to make this set out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather unclear what sort of objects are in R, but you seemto know how to manipulate them...

There is one error that may be causing you trouble:

`S = S.add(poly)`

is first adding `poly` to `S`, then assigning `None` to `S`, which is rather unfortunate.

#### try to replace it with:

`S.add(poly)`

which accumulates distinct objects into `S`

Comment: Thank you for your generosity！